# Why is this 8 puzzle unsolvable?

Tags: puzzle

I am developing a 8 puzzle game. I went through the rules in [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall12/cos226/assignments/8puzzle.html) (see **Detecting Unsolvable Puzzles**) link, which tell you how to detect if an initial state is unsolvable. It says that if the number of **inversions** is odd, then the goal state *cannot* be reached and if even the goal state *can* be reached.

An **inversion** is defined as follows:

> Given a board, an inversion is any pair of blocks i and j where i < j
>   but i appears after j when considering the board in row-major order
>   (row 0, followed by row 1, and so forth).

There is a 8-puzzle solver (applet) [here](http://www.brian-borowski.com/Software/Puzzle/). Choose 8-puzzle from the options.

```
1,0,3,2,4,5,6,7,8
```

and

```
7,0,2,8,5,3,6,4,1
```

As you can see both of them contain an even number of inversions. Still the program says that the puzzle is unsolvable. So is the `Princeton` link wrong?

Comment: Try solving `1,0,3,2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sequence 1,0,3,2,4,5,6,7,8 only has one inversion:

```
 1. 3,2
```

1 is odd, therefore this configuration is unsolvable.

Similarly, in 7,0,2,8,5,3,6,4,1:

```
 1. 7,2 
 2. 7,5 
 3. 7,3 
 4. 7,6 
 5. 7,4 
 6. 7,1 
 7. 2,1 
 8. 8,5 
 9. 8,3 
 10. 8,6 
 11. 8,4 
 12. 8,1 
 13. 5,3 
 14. 5,4 
 15. 5,1 
 16. 3,1 
 17. 6,4
 18. 6,1    
 19. 4,1
```

Nineteen inversions is odd.  Hence, unsolvable.

I think your mistake is that you're counting the "0" as if it was a tile, when you're working out the number of inversions.  But if you check the instructions in the article you linked, it isn't considering the blank space at all.

Comment: Yes you are right! I went through the source code of Utility.java in the site with the applet. They have not counted zero as you mentioned. That is where I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Ashwin, to be more precise, their notation is dodgy. If you look at the goal state, the blank tile should be `9` rather than `0`.

Comment: It appears like this board with 2 inversions cannot be solved: `2,1,3,4,5,6,8,7,0` with `0` being the blank tile, at least with my implementation of the A* approach as mentioned on the OP's post. The `f` value just keeps increasing...

Comment: Nvm, that board is indeed solvable and it takes 22 moves to do it!